# Syntax error on JS script

Tags: javascript, json, qgis

I have the following `.js` file, and Dreamweaver reports a syntax error on line 2.

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 0,
      "properties": {
        "Id": 0,
        "Title": "River & Trail HQ",
        "Other": null,
        "Parking": "Yes"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -8649997.6690437607,
          4769179.73322534
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Seems something is wrong with

```
"type": "FeatureCollection",
```

line.

Comment: Validates perfectly for me here: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: If that's the whole file, the problem is that it's simply not syntactically correct. That line is not a valid JavaScript statement.

Comment: @Wk_of_Angmar yes, it's valid **JSON**, but it's not valid **JavaScript**.

Comment: @Pointy: Good point. I just looked at the JSON tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that's the whole JavaScript file, then it's giving you an error because it's interpreted as a block instead of an object literal. To fix this, you could assign it to something, like

```
var someObj = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    ...
}
```

You may also be thinking of a JSON file (which is probably the case, since a free-floating object literal isn't going to do you much good anyway). JSON and JavaScript are not the same. If you really want a JSON file, then save it as such (`.json`).

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem, it required a variable

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var x = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",

"features": [
{ 
    "type": "Feature", "id": 0, "properties": 
    { 
        "Id": 0, "Title": "River & Trail HQ", "Other": null, "Parking": "Yes" 
    }, 
    "geometry": 
    { 
        "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -8649997.6690437607, 4769179.73322534 ] 
    } 
}
]};
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsonlint.com shows it as valid JSON and I can't see any issues with it on visual inspection.